# Using Apache LDAP Authentification on index.php/admin

Tags: php, linux, apache, ldap, limesurvey

I'm trying to find a solution about setting up a first stage LDAP Authetification for my LimeSurvey 2.0 installation. Now I'm facing the Problem, that I can just specify the directory which should get protected, but LimeSurvey uses index.php/admin for the admin interface. Is there any possibility to specifiy the code below from my vhost.conf for this exact file + "/admin"? Or do you know a better solution. Would be great if someone can help me.

Thanks a lot already!

```
<Directory />
    AuthLDAPUrl ldap://ldap.mydomain.com
    /ou=users,[...]
    AuthLDAPBindDN [...]
    AuthLDAPBindPassword [...]
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName [...]
    Require valid-user
    [...]
    Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to make LimeSurvey not have index.php in the URL by editing 
*/application/config/config.php* 
and setting

```
'showScriptName' => false,
```

That way the URL will more look like

```
http://yourdomain/limesurvey/admin/authentication/sa/login
```

and LDAP might work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not combine the apache basic auth with an PHP LDAP System?

```
<?php
// Check username and password:
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])){

    //store user
    $Username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    //store password
    $Password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

    //Here the LDAP auth should be in place. $ldap is the ldap connection protocol object
    if ($ldap->doAuth($Username,$Password)) {
        //perform XML data output, based on $ldap->userinformation

    } else {
        // The text inside the realm section will be visible for the
        // user in the login box
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Mobile Feed"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <x protocolversion="1" lang="nl">
            <x code="1">fail</fout>
        </x>   
        ';       
    }
}
?>
```

And combine this with the following library:
http://code.google.com/p/ldap-auth-php/

The above library has an include called protectsinglepage.php. You can include that in your main project. For the admin system just leave it out so it won't be protected by LDAP

Comment: Good luck mate, feel free to drop a line!